# Call GWT function from JavaScript (issue in IE)

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have 2 project. The first is GWT project

```
public class Ecoverage implements EntryPoint {
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Ecoverage.publish();
  }
  public static void getPayloadPage01() {
    Window.alert("alert from GWT module");
  }
  public static native void publish() /*-{
    $wnd.initPage01 = $entry(function () {
      @com.apps.client.Ecoverage::getPayloadPage01()();
    });
  }-*/;
}
```

The second one is regular dynamic web project with jsp.

page1.jsp

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    window.initPage01();
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Ecoverage/ecoverage/ecoverage.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
```

The pop-up windows is working fine in FF and Chrome but not in IE. IE says

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 18
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://10.0.2.2:8080/ecoverage-light/page1.jsp
```

The line 18 is: window.initPage01();

Let me know is there any workaround for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be  an timing issue? It seems that in IE the initPage01 function isnt present on page load. Not sure how GWT load it scripts in but as I remember it loads in the scripts in an iframe. So the onload in IE will fire earlier cause it dont check if the iframe is loaded.

After all why dont you open the popup from your GWT app. What are the benefits to open the popup direct onload instead of onModuleLoad?

Comment: it's just for testing, I am going to call the RPC service after the jsp page has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

@eskimoblood is probably right - `initPage01()` is called before scripts are fully loaded. Try using `scheduleDeferred()` - put this in your `onModuleLoad()`:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // your commands here
            Ecoverage.publish();
    }
});
```